# The security database on the server does not have a computer account for this workstation trust relationship

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory

I have a Server 2008 machine called OTTO
I recently, by mistake, booted up an old machine, also called OTTO (the hardware was unstable, so the new one was set up to take it's place)

I shut down the old machine, turned it off, and recycled it (it won't ever be back on)

Now, whenever i try to log in to the **real** OTTO with the domain account (mydomain\Administrator) i get the following error:

> The security database on the server does not have a computer account for this workstation

What can I do to fix this?

It doesn't appear in active directory any more
I've added it, but I'm guessing this had no effect, due to a different SID

I can log in as the local administrator however

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest fix is to place "OTTO" back into a "Workgroup" and re-join the domain. (Be sure you have a good local Administrator credential on OTTO when you're doing this...)  I'm unsure how just booting the old machine caused this issue, but disjoining and rejoining the domain will resolve the problem.